# How to specify which page to get the gallery images from using wp_get_attachment_image_src function

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

The code currently gets all the images from the media gallery. I am trying to get the images from a gallery on a specific page. How can I achieve that?

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'desc',
        'posts_per_page' => '30',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit'
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_the_ID(), $size = 'full');
    echo
    "<div class='col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3'>
        <div class='gallery-img-wrap'>
            <img src='" . $image[0] . "'>
        </div>
    </div>";

    endwhile;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'desc',
    'posts_per_page' => '30',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'post_parent'    => 52 //page id
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_the_ID(), $size = 'full');
echo
"<div class='col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3'>
    <div class='gallery-img-wrap'>
        <img src='" . $image[0] . "'>
    </div>
</div>";

endwhile;
```

?>

Comment: tried adding the post parent line but then all the images disappeared.

Comment: Essa galeria é um padrão do wordpress ou de algum tema ou plugin?

Comment: It is a wordpress gallery. I am trying to display it without needing an additional plugin.